# Custom mezzanine Profile

Tags: django, mezzanine, accounts

I have some problems with my mezzanine project.

1) I created the custom Profile model and used settings.AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE;

2) I declared ACCOUNTS_PROFILE_FORM_EXCLUDE_FIELDS for a limitation of set of fields in custom Profile model;

3) Custom Profile is working correctly with templates of Profile, Signup and Update.

But I want to separate set of fields between templates of Profile and Signup in my app.  Also, I want to control set of fields for SignupForm through settings param, like as ACCOUNTS_PROFILE_FORM_EXCLUDE_FIELDS. But I have no idea and experience how to do it.

What is a practice? I'll be happy links or examples! Thanks!